# Planning to travel YYC-CDG 2E-DEL on separate tickets with baggage recheck needed. Indian Passport & Canadian PR. Is a visa required?

Tags: air-travel, schengen-visas, transit-visas, airport-transfer

Ticket 1
YYC - CDG
Westjet flight WS10
Arrival Terminal 2E in Paris

Ticket 2
CDG - DEL
Vistara Flight UK 22
Departure Terminal 2E in Paris

Baggage recheck is required as these are not partner airlines.

I have an Indian passport and a valid Permanent Residence of Canada.

Do I need a transit visa or Schengen visa in this case?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do I need a visa to transit (or layover) in the Schengen area?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-or-layover-in-the-schengen-area)

Comment: Since baggage check is necessary, you'll need a regular Schengen visa.

Comment: If I travel with just carry on bags, can I make the trip without schengen visa?